# How to remove duplicates from ArrayList<Object> with duplicate values

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a object e.g.

```
public class name{

int age;
localdatetime borndate; 

//getter/setters etc..

}
```

I am given a `List<name>` , sorted by `localdatetime` in `desc` order. I want to compare `age` variable the objects in the ArrayList. If there are other occurances of people with same age, then remove everyone else and keep the latest value.

e.g.
Say i have the below data set :

```
new name(13,12/02/2005)
new name(12,12/02/2004)
new name(13,12/02/2004)
new name(14,12/02/2004)
```

I would expect

```
new name(13,12/02/2005)
new name(12,12/02/2004)
new name(14,12/02/2004)
```

I have tried to do it with a nested loop but not sure if that is the best approach?

Comment: I believe nested loop is a good approach. What is your suspicion about nested loop.

Comment: I imagine that when large sets of data (in millions) are used, it would have a great impact on performance

Comment: Then you can store data as sorted according to age while inserting and using binary search you can easily check whether this is duplicate or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a map to store found entries and to perform checks if anything already found for the age as you only want one for any given age. As your data is already sorted in the order you want use `LinkedHashMap` to preserve sorting order:

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, name> data = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, name>();
for (name item: list) {
    Integer age = Integer.valueOf(name.age);
    if (!data.containsKey(age)) {
        data.put(age, name);
    }
}
return data.values();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use first contains method of array list to check duplicate entry. If found then use remove method of array list.

Comment: You mean using indexOf?

Comment: First check using contains. The if found use remove method and pass the indexOf method in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize the data and put it into a HashSet, then converting that back to an ArrayList.

Example with Integers:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        ints.add(rand.nextInt(100));
    }
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    set.addAll(ints);
    ints.clear();
    ints.addAll(set);
```

Not the most memory-efficient way (although it's O(N)), but easily the most readable...

This works because the Set only contains unique values. At the end of that snippet, *ints* would contain only unique values.

And like another post below me suggested, use a LinkedHashSet to preserve the original item order.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 approach (with actually working Java code):

```
public class Name {
    int age;
    Date borndate;

    public Name(int age, String borndate) throws ParseException {
        this.age = age;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YYYY");
        this.borndate = sdf.parse(borndate);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 59 * hash + this.age;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Name other = (Name) obj;
        return this.age == other.age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return age + " : " + borndate;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        List<Name> l = Arrays.asList(new Name(13, "12/02/2005"), 
            new Name(12, "12/02/2004"), new Name(13, "12/02/2004"), 
            new Name(14, "12/02/2004"));
        l = l.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(l);
    }

}
```